# How to move a string from a register into memory

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

How to move a string from a register into memory

I have a string value, 'Fred', in a register and I want to move it into memory. If I do the move directly, it will flip the bytes, for example:

```
mov $0x46726564, %eax
movl %eax, -4(%rbp)

(gdb) >>> x/4c $rbp-4
0x7fffffffe334: 100 'd' 101 'e' 114 'r' 70 'F'
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: `bswap %eax`. Or just put the bytes into the correct order to start with.

Comment: @Jester thanks for the response. I see, yea I think I should try and move the pointers around instead of the actual string values, which gets rid of the above issue.

Comment: If you want to write code with convenient multi-character immediates in memory order, use a better assembler, e.g. NASM.  `mov dword [rbp -4], 'Fred'` stores that 4-byte sequence to memory in source order.  In GAS, you could write it like `movl $'F' + ('r'<<8) + ('e'<<16) + ('d'<<24), -4(%rbp)` because x86 is little-endian.  But GAS doesn't let you write `$'Fred'` as a 4-byte numeric constant.  There are times where you want to construct something in memory from immediate values, like compilers will do for small local arrays like `char foo[] = "Fred"`.